# input on reference or on pointer return type functions

Tags: c++, class, pointers, input, reference

I’ve written the following code but i don't know very well why it worked.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class temp_class
{
private:
    char id[20];
    char name[20];
    float price;
public:
    temp_class();
    char*getid();
    char*getname();
    float&getprice();
    void print()const;
};
temp_class::temp_class()
{
    strcpy(id,"unknown");
    strcpy(name,"unknown");
    price=0.0;
}
char*temp_class::getid(){return id;}
char*temp_class::getname(){return name;}
float&temp_class::getprice(){return price;}
void temp_class::print()const
{
    cout<<"ID : "<<id<<" / Name : "<<name<<" / Price : "<<price<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int n=0;
    cout<<"Enter Number of Items : ";
    cin>>n;
    temp_class*T=new temp_class[n];
    for(;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter ID,Name,and price for Item "<<i+1<<" : ";
        cin>>T[i].getid()>>T[i].getname()>>T[i].getprice();//the user will input on the 
    }                                                    //returned data members 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)                                        //but why it worked ?
    { 
        T[i].print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so i think the reason that made it work it's because float&getprice() return price by reference so the input made on it will take affect on it's memory location , char*getid() return a pointer to the first memory cell of id and by default changes on array will take effect because it's send by reference (by default) and the same for char*getname() i think;

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I think you would be better off using `std::string` instead of `char*`/`char[]`!

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. getprice() returns a reference to the class member which can then be modified by the caller. For the `char*` there is a special overload to treat them as strings. Since only the pointer to the actual string is returned by-value, the actual string can be modified again.

If you want to avoid this kind of behaviour you can add the `const` keyword to your return values